# I want create data entry and input STOCK data in google sheet by copying from whatsapp

Tags: google-apps-script

I want create data entry and input STOCK data by copying from whatsapp

stock data that I input is always not the same number of rows

data is stored based on the selected date, for example: if the chosen date is 18 Apr 2020 then the data will be stored on the "18 Apr 2020" tab

if you choose date 18 Apr 2020 and the operator named REGINA then the data will be saved in the "18 Apr 2020" tab and in the REGINA column

if i select CODE = " A01" then automatic save in CODE column according to the number of numbers that existed before x ( see 18 Apr 2020 tab )

The data of  STOCK is divided into 2 format dan 2 functions
If the data not have format , or . and x then the data can't be save and show notif " the format data not valid"
the first part is a number separated by commas or periods
the second part is after the character x which means the quantity in each number before X

if I click the save button the contents of the data will be empty
in the date section, the operator and code won't change if I don't change it
the order in the tab section Apr 18 2020 is descended according to the column and will fill in the last empty row
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15wuMkIOAcBKoUTKJDkniZJe3JrbRVgmywj62f7quMU0/edit?usp=sharing

i try copy this code but not work:

````
var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var formSS    = ss.getSheetByName("DATA ENTRY"); //Data entry Sheet
var datasheet = ss.getSheetByName("DATA"); //Data Sheet

//Input Values
var values = [
[formSS.getRange("E5").getValue(),
formSS.getRange("E7").getValue(),
formSS.getRange("E9").getValue(),
formSS.getRange("E13").getValue(),
]
           ];

datasheet.getRange(datasheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 4).setValues(values);

}```
````

Comment: Welcome. Please follow the [tour], read [ask] and [edit] your question to make a specific question according to the guidelines of this site.

Comment: Please post your code in the question. I wont follow links to spreadsheets.

Comment: Why does the code not  work? What happens and what do you expect to see?

Comment: Hello @AdidasGajah - can you please be more specific about your goal? And why isn't the code posted working?